# “app has stopped” error with release React Native project on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

When the application is executed normally it works but when release the application the application does not execute on the phone(app has stopped).
react native version:
this package.json file:

```
  * {
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.1.2",
    "color": "^3.0.0",
    "native-base": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "^16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-exit-app": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.6",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.0.28",
    "react-navigation": "^1.5.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
}*
```

used code:
react-native run-android --variant=release

or

$ cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease

Answer (score 0):

We could do with a little more detail around this and ideally a stack trace (although I realise that can be tricky with release builds).

I'll take a guess that your release build has "minify" (proguard obfuscation and possibly code shrinking) turned on. The crash *could* be caused by a method being renamed during this process (and causing a crash if used via reflection) or even removed (again, causing a crash).

Good luck. You might get some more insight if you give a bit more detail.